# "Name * not defined" in nested python comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iterator, generator

I have gathered information in a dictionnary of this form:

```
dico = {
        'key1': ('el1', 'el2', 'el3'),
        'key2': ('el4',),
        'key3': ('el5', 'el6'),
        }
```

I wish to iterate over it in such a way that this would produce:

```
>>> for i in gen:
...    print(i)
('key1', 'el1')
('key1', 'el2')
('key1', 'el3')
('key2', 'el4')
('key3', 'el5')
('key3', 'el6')
```

So here is how I build `gen`:

```
gen = ((key, value) for value in values for key, values in dico.items())
```

But this throws a `NameError`:

```
NameError: name 'values' is not defined
```

What is wrong? How should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse the order so that the names resolve:

```
gen = ((key, value) for (key, values) in dico.items() for value in values)
```

The for loops should be in the same order as if you'd write:

```
for key, values in dico.items():
    for value in values:
        yield key, value
```

Comment: So that was it! Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to list the loops in the order you'd nest them, from left to right. You swapped that order.

This works:

```
gen = ((key, value) for key, values in dico.items() for value in values)
```

which corresponds with how you'd nest those loops in a generator function:

```
for key, values in dico.items():
    for value in values:
        yield (key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to reverse the order of gen generation code.

dico = {
        'key1': ('el1', 'el2', 'el3'),
        'key2': ('el4',),
        'key3': ('el5', 'el6'),
        }
gen = ((key, value) for (key, values) in dico.items() for value in values)
for i in gen:
    print(i)

>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
('key1', 'el1')
('key1', 'el2')
('key1', 'el3')
('key2', 'el4')
('key3', 'el5')
('key3', 'el6')
>>> 

How bellow code is eveluated:
gen = ((key, value) for (key, values) in dico.items() for value in values)

step 1: for (key, values) in dico.items()
step 2: values of step 1 will be input for bellow code:
        for value in values
step 3: then for every value it will store the key, value pair in gen
dictionary.
```